# R Fitting polynomial to data through (a) fixed point(s)

Tags: r, interpolation, curve-fitting, polynomials

I'm stuck at a very specific problem where I have to find a function describing the (normalized) leaf shape of a plant. The problem is not just to find the polynomial that best describes the data, but also that it starts at (0,0) ends at (1,0) and moves through the point of maximum width (x_ymax, 1) without ever going wider.

An alternate option I tried is Hermite interpolation, using those 3 specific points as control points but the function it provides is way off the actual shape of the leaf, unless I provide more control points.

Is there a specific function for this or do I need to make some manual conversion? Or would there be better or alternate options to tackling this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are some methods discusses in [this paper](http://www.silvafennica.fi/article/1019) - maybe it helpful.

Comment: Yes, that paper was my inspiration to even try hermite interpolation, however my shapes were still way off. I have now adapted my own model to describe these shapes, no longer relying on a simple mathematical function.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this would always work, but here is an example of a "Generalized Additive Model" that uses a cyclic spline. When you specify that the model should not have an intercept (i.e. include `-1` in formula, then it should pass through y=0. You will have to scale your predictor variable to be between 0 and 1 in order for the ends to pass through the points you mentioned (see [here](http://www.fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2014/05/09/modelling-seasonal-data-with-gam/) for more info.).

#### Example

```
# required model
library(mgcv)

# make data
n <- 200
tmp <- seq(0,20*pi,,n)
x <- tmp / (2*pi)
mon <- x%%1
err <- rnorm(n, sd=0.5)
y <- sin(tmp) + err + 1
plot(x, y, t="l")
df <- data.frame(x, y, mon)

# GAM with intercept
fit1 <- gam(y ~ s(mon, bs = "cc", k = 12), data=df)
summary(fit1)
plot(fit1)

# GAM without intercept
fit2 <- gam(y ~ s(mon, bs = "cc", k = 12) - 1, data=df) # note "-1" for no intercept
summary(fit2)
plot(fit2)
```

[image]

Comment: It's an interesting idea but the leaf shape I'm trying to describe differs quite a bit from the potential shape a GAM could provide. I'm currently simply working with a 10th degree polynomial as the main goal is not a predictive model but a descriptive one. However, should it be possible to lower the amount of parameters (by getting a comparable fit with the constraints written in the original question) it would have my preference. An example shape (plotting the 3 extreme points on the data) is given [here](http://i.imgur.com/JieQpeY.png)